# API for list of delegated (signed in) apps from Google Workspace

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

Within Google Workspace > Users > {user name} > Security, there is a list of all applications that the user has authenticated into using their Google Workspace user SSO.

We are trying to pull this list for each user on the Google Workspace account via API. Could anyone point to the correct API to access this list from?:

[image: google workspace sso connections list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are interested in the `tokens` resource of the Google Admin Directory API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list